# Apk Expansion file is not downloaded through emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, apk-expansion-files

My app is uploaded to play store, it has an APK expansion file.  Tested in real devices and working OK. Some times I get crash reports and I want to simulate them in the emulator.
I get this message" `Download failed because the resources could not be found`"

Here is the Logcat:

> E/Checking_download: service_to_connected : 
>   E/Checking_download: service_connected : 
>   E/Checking_download: DownloadStateChanged : Looking for resources to download
>   E/vending: [125] VendingApplication.getAuthTokenBlocking(): no matching accounts for ANDROID
>   E/vending: [125] AsynchRequestRunner$1.runRequestRetryingFailure(): Got ApiException from async request: Sent a bad request.
>   E/vending: [125] VendingApplication.getAuthTokenBlocking(): no matching accounts for ANDROID
>   E/vending: [125] AsynchRequestRunner$1.runRequestRetryingFailure(): Got ApiException from async request: Sent a bad request.
>   E/vending: [125] VendingApplication.getAuthTokenBlocking(): no matching accounts for ANDROID
>   E/vending: [125] AsynchRequestRunner$1.runRequestRetryingFailure(): Got ApiException from async request: Sent a bad request.
>   E/vending: [125] VendingApplication.getAuthTokenBlocking(): no matching accounts for ANDROID
>   E/vending: [125] AsynchRequestRunner$1.runRequestRetryingFailure(): Got ApiException from async request: Sent a bad request.
>   E/vending: [125] VendingApplication.getAuthTokenBlocking(): no matching accounts for ANDROID
>   E/vending: [125] AsynchRequestRunner$1.runRequestRetryingFailure(): Got ApiException from async request: Sent a bad request.
>   E/vending: [125] VendingApplication.getAuthTokenBlocking(): no matching accounts for ANDROID
>   E/vending: [125] AsynchRequestRunner$1.runRequestRetryingFailure(): Got ApiException from async request: Sent a bad request.
>   E/Checking_download: DownloadStateChanged : Download failed because the resources could not be found
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isRestrictedUserProfile
>   E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send app launch
>   E/FA: Failed to get app instance id
>   E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
>   E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
>   E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service

Noting that I tried many Google APIs. 26,27,.....

The above logcat is from API 15.

Emulator Config:-
[image]
Thanks for usual support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you definitely running an emulator with Google Play Services and the Play store on it? From that logcat it looks like you aren't. If you definitely are, are they up to date?

Comment: The configuration is Android 4.0.3(Google APIs). I added a screen shot for AVD manager above. They are up to date as I just installed them 2 days ago. I checked again SDK manager, no updates available. Thx.

Comment: You need one that has the Play store. See this blog post: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/google-play-system-images-android.html

Comment: I changed Google API to Google Play and the error changed to "Download failed because you may not have purchased this app", which means your solution is accepted

Comment: To clarify, if it shows 'Google APIs' in the emulator config, it is not the required Google Play enable emulator. Go to **Tools -> AVD Manager** and create or edit a virtual device. Look at the recommended list - 'Google Play' in brackets.